# How to retrieve block-length of an IceCast-Stream?

Tags: c#, .net, shoutcast, icecast

IceCast is very similar to Shoutcast which gives you its data-block-length in the header via icy-metaint.

The stream I work with (an IceCast-stream) doesn't seem to have such a value.

How can I retrieve the length of a data-block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if the icecast server is setup not to send metadata and/or the stream client is not sending any metadata in the stream. If you have more details let us know. Considering how long this is open, doubt it's still a problem. Leaving my answer here to any other stragglers :-)

Comment: It is sending metadata, but only stuff like Artist or Title. There's no hint on the block-length.

Comment: Can you share a dump of the request headers and response headers ? WireShark is your friend.